# How to block IP range with nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

In my server, I use nginx as web server.
This server receives many visits from bad bots.

I know how to block specific ip, editing /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and within the server block, add this line (example): `deny 74.208.136.135;`

But I want to block all access from `74.208.***.***`

Is this possible with nginx?

Comment: Check the example which is the first thing [in the documentation for `deny`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#example)

Comment: Use CIDR network address: `deny 75.208.0.0/16;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer as already been told in the comments

deny accepts as stated in [NGINX Manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html):

- hostname
- IP
- CIDR
- Unix-Socket
- All

Meaning:

> deny my.blocked.host 
> deny 127.0.0.1 
> deny 127.0.0.1/8 
> deny unix:/path/to/socket 
> deny all

The answer to your Request, which is used to Block a *Class A Network* which is the same as Netmask *255.255.0.0* or in *CIDR /16*

the Answer to your Question

```
deny 75.208.0.0/16;
```

Comment: @Diego-Somar i hope i could help you with your Question and would be really glad if you accept it as answer

Comment: Hello @djdomi tks your answer. I applied the change on the server, thanks :)

Comment: it's Class B not A, damn auto correction ;-) Class A would be 255.0.0.0 or /8 to be fully correct